# Informatica Expression transformation logic change

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

I have a code in **Informatica** that is currently *rejecting* any record that has a `ROLE_ID` other than '**Primary Annuitant**', I need to make a change to reject any record with `ROLE_ID` other than '**Secondary Annuitant**' and '**Primary Annuitant**'.

Here is the current logic

```
IIF(ROLE_ID<>'PRIMARY ANNUITANT ','Invalid ROLE_ID'),
```

Need to stop Rejecting '**Secondary Annuitant**'

Please Advise

Comment: Have you tried `not in`?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the `IIF` in many ways.

```
IIF(ROLE_ID<>'PRIMARY ANNUITANT ' AND ROLE_ID<>'SECONDARY ANNUITANT ','Invalid ROLE_ID'),
```

OR

```
IIF(ROLE_ID<>'PRIMARY ANNUITANT ' ,
 IIF (ROLE_ID<>'SECONDARY ANNUITANT ','Invalid ROLE_ID')),...
```

OR

```
IIF(NOT IN(ROLE_ID,'PRIMARY ANNUITANT ','SECONDARY ANNUITANT ',0),'Invalid ROLE_ID')...
```

This will produce 'Invalid ROLE_ID' in case of anything other than primary and secondary annuitant. Pls note also I just reused your code and i am not sure about all of your code.